# How to create a page location in browser using javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a setup where I display a list of buttons and clicking on the buttons triggers a function that contacts a firebase database and gets the contents of a 'slide' that is to be shown to the user. The function then clears the content of the page and then creates elements from the data acquired from the database.

Now obviously, when I press back browser button once I've replaced the content, it won't take me back to the previous content. But I believe that my user's experience will be much better if it actually took them back to the list of buttons. I have two faint ideas on how to go about solving this problem but I'm lacking in specific details of how I can go about it.

**Possible Solution 1:**
Some way to dynamically create a new page using javascript and then serve it to the user.

**Possible Solution 2:** 
Some way to simulate that the page has changed location. Maybe using anchoring links.

Let me know if you have any other solutions in mind or if you know how I should go about implementing these. Your help will be much appreciated. :D

Comment: Have you looked into routing? https://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/

Comment: Second solution. URIs containing hash fragments will appear in the history. So each time you load a new slide, change the hash of the page. Something like `http://www.myserver.com.myPage/#/slide1`. Then you can also check upon load if there's already a hash fragment set in the URL. If so, load that slide again.

Comment: I just did something similar, try using .pushState https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: Alright, I'll check out each solution and see what works for me. Thanks for the quick response guys. :D